# How to automate Home,back,up,down,Menu button at bottom of Android phone using appium java client 6.1.0?

Tags: java, automation, appium, mobile-application, appium-android

I am new to appium and trying to automate one android native app but currently I am blocked as I am not able to inspect back,Home,Active app button present at bottom of Android phone screen.

I googled a lot about it but everywhere I found use of method “pressKeyCode(int key)” but this method is currently deprecated
(https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/nativekey/PressesKey.html)

I tried new method pressKey(KeyEvent keyEvent) but still not working.

Request to please help or let me know any reference where I can get details regarding.

PFB part of code:

AndroidDriver driver;

```
driver=new AndroidDriver(new URL(“http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub”), cap);

driver.pressKey(KeyEvent(KEYCODE_MENU))); // KEYCODE_MENU can not be resolved
driver.pressKey(withKey(AndroidKey.HOME)))); //The method home is undefined for the type AndroidKey.
```

Comment: You can try adb commands. You can easily get the adb commands by googling

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Device Level back Button, such as hardware back button

Please import below packages

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent;
```

use the function

```
driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.BACK));
```

Answer (score 1):

For recent button functionality on android you can use:

```
driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.APP_SWITCH));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to use Appium Java API, I suggest to go through tests in [appium-java-client](https://github.com/appium/java-client) repo.

Particular your example is [here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/KeyCodeTest.java):

`driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.HOME));`

Comment: Thanks for help, This worked for me. Sure I will go through tests suggested by you.